# Horizontal tab gallery (i don't know how to call that)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm new here but you already helped me quite a lot in the past.
I'm building a website for my company and i'm learning as i'm going forward.
Right now i'm building with Dreamweaver and Bootstrap but i have a problem.
I would like to add a section (multiple one, but i can copy and paste to get a similar result) with a portfolio.
The problem is that i don't even know how to call what i want.
I would like 4 "tab" on a row with an image, white if active, grey if not, and by clicking the image on top, i would like a small arrow (possibly one designed by me) pointing down to the content, some text and an image.

So far i've achieved this results with some columns, but of course is not what i want because i would like the content in the bottom to be spreaded and not only below the top image.

After that i've considered the carousel with some tweaking, still, is not what i want, maybe similar, but it's not the same. And of coure, i still have the problem of the image color. Infact, i don't know if i have to use both pictures or there is a command.

In summary, just to give you a better image of what i would like, imagine something like Firefox or Chrome tabs, with a small arrow underneath if selected and the icon of the selected one white. Below that the content, occupying th whole width.

I'm sorry if i said something wrong, but as i said, i'm (slowly) learning.

EDIT: here's a visual example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjh7m.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but don't use Dreamweaver. It is a web developer's nightmare. Use a modern IDE such as brackets.io, atom.io or code.visualstudio.com.

Comment: @JosephA. no not agree with you. Dreamweaver helps a lot for beginners. One needs not to be depend on Dw..thats it.

Comment: @JosephA. as i said, i'm learning, i'm not afraid to say that i'm a noob, i don't like DW either, but it gives me some hints in what i'm doing, like templates and other stuff. In the future i'm sure i'll look elsewhere, but right now, it's pretty handy, at least to understand visually what i'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably bootstrap's tabs will help you:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Html code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/1801/

Comment: Thanks, it's a good start. There is a problem tho, i can't go back and forth between those tabs, One they are selected i can't see them until i refresh

Comment: Is there some kind of restriction on selecting these tabs? Can you please give me some more details on it?

Comment: I would like something like Chrome tabs, so switching back and forth to read what's below depending on what you select on top. I'll put you a screenshot of my sketch. http://imgur.com/0h1VQVQ

Comment: So this is exactly what's happening in my given example. You can switch back and forth to read what's below depending on what you selected on top. Moreover you can replace text of tabs by images to look it same you have shared in sketch.

Comment: And what about grey image? I mean, they should be white when selected, with the arrow below (the one in the sketch), and grey when not in use. Is there some code for that? Again, sorry but I'm really new to all of this and Dreamweaver sometimes is not that helpful

Comment: Here is your solution:

_Create two different images (one with white color having arrow pointing at bottom and second with grey color without arrow). Now, create two classes to set these images in background lets say tab_white and tab_grey. Use grey as default and white as active. Change the classes on click event._

Here is the running demo:
[https://plnkr.co/edit/sDLTPzkt4OyxZwuKpGm7?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/sDLTPzkt4OyxZwuKpGm7?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! Done! Unfortunately the greyscale doesn't work properly, so i opted for opacity instead, in this way i don't have to upload two different image and loading is going to be faster. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ohh, great!! I'm happy for that.